# Массив записей

Tags: массивы, java

Недавно начал изучать Java.
Пишу телефоную книгу для практики.
Создал 2 класса для хранения 1 записи - Note
для хранения Note - создал класс PhoneNotes. Где в массиве храню записи.
Но я не знаю точно сколько у меня будет записей, 1 или 1000.
Как обойти создание массива? Или как хранить кипу записей, чтоб удобно было по ним ходить?

Comment: Вы хотите хранить массив данных без использования массива? Это нонсенс! Или я чего-то не понял в вопросе!

Comment: да. Вы чегото не понимаете.

Answer (score 5):

используй коллекции, например ArrayList()

Answer (score 2):

массив не нужен.
пользуйте Java Collections Framework